Differences in Shutdown Output Between mongo Shell and mongosh Shell
I am encountering differing outputs when trying to shut down my MongoDB server using the mongo shell and the mongosh shell, and I want to understand why this is happening.
I executed the following commands in their respective shells:
Using mongo shell:
mongo --port 45768 --username **** --password **** --authenticationDatabase admin --eval "db.getSiblingDB('admin').shutdownServer()"

OUTPUT:
MongoDB shell version v5.0.22
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:45768/?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("3f613e46-c850-4ac6-ba12-51267ef98e9d") }
MongoDB server version: 5.0.22
server should be down...
{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-03T09:02:41.898Z"},"s":"I",  "c":"QUERY",    "id":22791,   "ctx":"js","msg":"Failed to end logical session","attr":{"lsid":{"id":{"$uuid":"3f613e46-c850-4ac6-ba12-51267ef98e9d"}},"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] server [couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:45768, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:45768 :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.]"}}}

Using mongosh shell:
mongosh --port 64352 --username **** --password **** --authenticationDatabase admin --eval "db.getSiblingDB('admin').shutdownServer()"

output:
Error: read ECONNRESET



MongoDB version: 5.0.22
mongo shell version: v5.0.22
mongosh version: 2.3.3
MongoDB version: 6.0.19

Is there any functional difference in how the shutdown command is processed between these two shells?
How can I ensure consistency in behavior and logging across these shells for shutdown operations?

The outputs of legacy mongo shell mongo and mongosh are slightly different. Unless you process the output with other tools, there is nothing you have to worry about.

Thank you for the reply. In our code, we are shutting down the MongoDB server using the mongo shell. However, after upgrading to MongoDB 6, we switched to mongosh
Now, when we execute the shutdown command, we encounter an issue with the
Process process = builder.start();
int waitFor = process.waitFor();
if (0 != waitFor) {
return ("Command execution failed[waitFor=" + waitFor + "].");
}
After executing the shutdown command, the waitFor() method returns 1, resulting in the error: Command execution failed[waitFor=1] why this might happen with mongosh and how to resolve it?

Seems to be difficult. Maybe ignore the return code and check if the process (retrieved by db.runCommand( { serverStatus: 1 } ).pid.toString()) is still existing.

Those look like very similar errors, ECONNREFUSED vs ECONNRESET, with neither one explicitly telling you that the server is down, just that the connection to the server is gone. In the mongod source code for the shutdown command there is a comment: Client expects the shutdown command to abruptly close the socket as part of exiting., so I don't think there is a way to confirm the shutdown command succeeded remotely, you'll need to check the log for the Terminating via shutdown command and exit code.

Thanks for your suggestion! I started the mongod process on port 23451 and then attempted to shut it down using mongosh. The shutdown was successful. However, when I checked the network state afterward using netstat, I observed the following:
C:\Users\gsairam>netstat -ano | findstr 23451
TCP    127.0.0.1:49232        127.0.0.1:23451        TIME_WAIT       0
This indicates the port was still in the TIME_WAIT state briefly after the shutdown.
In contrast, when I shut down the MongoDB server using the mongo shell on port 56473, and then ran the same netstat command: It displayed nothing
